# Google drive code gives error when adding trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-drive-api, server-error

When I add triggers in google script my google drive to load a folder stops working, does anybody know why it is causing this and a fix? The code works if I don't add the triggers.

> Error msg: "We're sorry a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

Below is the code: 
`function test() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID);
}`

The code is embedded in a spreadsheet, all I did was add a trigger that calls this function when a form is submitted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Comment: Hello, please post your code and some simple steps to reproduce the error.

Comment: See my edited post.

Comment: For me it works fine, are you still encountering this issue?

Comment: Yes I am. And I think the reason is not even trigger related now. I removed the trigger still same problem.

Comment: Which runtime version are you using?

Comment: V8, I found the cause of the problem. Since I am integrating with Slack I needed to add Drive API from slack and that solved the problem.